# I am trying to read a tab delimited text file and store certain parts of the data in different fields in a matlab structure

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to read a plain text, tab delimited file format. I need to read both the strings and the numerical values. The issue is that the table doesn't start until the third row, the first two rows contain version information and info on the size of the data. When I try to use normal methods like load and import data I end up with an error message saying that the columns in line 2 do not match the columns in line 1.

I have written some code to read the file line by line which I will attach. I need to figure out how to make a structure with 4 fields

This is my code

```
fid = fopen('gene_expr_500x204.gct');
s = struct[]
% read the first 2 lines and do nothing to them
for k=1:3
    tline = fgets(fid);
end
% next reading will be on 3rd line.
% display from 3rd line forward:
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgets(fid);
end
fclose(fid)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not just use the column offset of `dlmread` to skip the first two lines?

Comment: I actually did do that but dlmread, as far as I know, only retrieves numerical data. I need to store not just the numbers but the column/row names in a few different fields of a structure.

Comment: It would help if you uploaded a 10-line or so example file to your post

Comment: Yes that is a good suggestion, I'll try to get a little sample of the file in there. You can also see a picture of what it looks like if you follow that link in the post

Comment: I realize that, but it's unclear how many columns you have etc.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up that portion of my post! Still a little new to this. The number of columns is 206

Comment: @embryo3699 please read the updated answer

Comment: @Umar do either of you know if it is possible to store a matrix in a structure field? I now have a structure with the three cell array fields that I mentioned but haven't been able to figure out the matrix part

Comment: @embryo3699 please read the updated answer and let me know if this was what you were asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `textscan` to parse this file format. Using the file format, we can read in how many rows and columns are expected. We can then read the headers and place these into a cell array. Then we can create a custom format spec for each of the remaining rows and read in the rest of the file. Once we have that, we can combine the headers with the data to construct a `struct` with fields that match the headers.

This solution is flexible as it actually *parses* the file format itself to determine the number of columns rather than hard-coding a particular value in.

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt', 'r');

% Skip the first line and determine the number or rows and number of samples
dims = textscan(fid, '%d', 2, 'HeaderLines', 1);
ncols = dims{1}(2);

% Now read the variable names
varnames = textscan(fid, '%s', 2 + ncols);
varnames = varnames{1};

% Now create the format spec for your data (2 strings and the rest floats)
spec = ['%s%s', repmat('%f', [1 ncols])];

% Read in all of the data using this custom format specifier. The delimiter will be a tab
data = textscan(fid, spec, 'Delimiter', '\t');

% Place the data into a struct where the variable names are the fieldnames
inputs = cat(1, varnames(:)', data);
S = struct(inputs{:});

%   7x1 struct array with fields:
%
%   Name
%   Desc
%   A2
%   B2
%   C2
%   D2
%   E2
%   F2
%   G2
%   H2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been very helpful. I'm new to stack academy but what is the best way for me to improve your account reputation/ make your answering this question worthwhile?

Comment: @embryo3699 upvoting and accepting answers is the currency around here. I'm glad to help out. Let me know if you have any issues with this

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method

```
fileID = fopen('gene_expr_500x204.gct','r+');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s%s%s%s') %assuming you have 4 columns
```

and you can seperate the data by using

```
numericaldata = str2double(C{1}(3:end))
string data = C{1}(1:2)
```

Well assuming the number of columns are unknown just use

```
 delimiter = '\t'
 fid = fopen('testtext3.txt','rt');
 tLines = fgets(fid);
 numCols = numel(strfind(tLines,delimiter)) + 1;
 formatSpec = repmat(['%s'],1,numCols )
```

or if the number of columns are known just

```
KnownColumns = 206;
formatSpec = repmat(['%s'],1,KnownColumns)
```

**UPDATE:**
About your second question , actually you can store any data type to a structure field, I have given the method below 
    a = {[1 2 3 ],'CO'}

```
a = 

    [1x3 double]    'CO'

b = table([1 2 3].','VariableNames',{'Heading'})

b = 

    Heading
    _______

    1      
    2      
    3      

 c = [1 2 3;4 5 6]

c =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6

Struc(1).DataTypes = a

Struc(2).DataTypes = b

Struc(3).DataTypes = c

struct2table(Struc)

ans = 

     DataTypes  
    ____________

    {1x2 cell  }
    [3x1 table ]
    [2x3 double]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It is actually a pretty large data set, so my other question would be how can I get formatspec to deal with 200+ columns?

Comment: do you know the number of columns ?

Comment: or atleast do you the delimiter?

Comment: Yes there are 206 comments and the delimiter is \t

Comment: columns* not comments

Comment: Thank you Umar! This has been very helpful

Comment: Mention not ! Let me know if need anymore help with this