# I am trying to read the time and message value field data as shown below and write it to an excel

Tags: matlab

Sample data and required excel image:

[image: Sample data and required excel image]

Also, Read `Time` section as shown in file, and populate excel file with the data in a column with the header name `Time` as shown above. Likewise, read the message value as shown in the .asc file and populate in excel file by converting the numbers from hexadecimal to decimal in columns named `Data1`, `Data2`, `Data3`,…

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, how does your current code look like

Answer (score 0):

If your '.asc' file consists of tab delimited ASCII text then Excel will allow you to import it into an Excel worksheet.

The following explainer comes from Microsoft's [Office support site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmimport_data_from_a_text_file_by_openi):

> There are two ways to import data from a text file by using Microsoft
>   Excel: You can open the text file in Excel, or you can import the text
>   file as an external data range. To export data from Excel to a text
>   file, use the Save As command.
>
> There are two commonly used text file formats:
>
> Delimited text files (.txt), in which the TAB character (ASCII
>   character code 009) typically separates each field of text.
>
> Comma separated values text files (.csv), in which the comma character
>   (,) typically separates each field of text.
>
> You can change the separator character that is used in both delimited
>   and .csv text files. This may be necessary to make sure that the
>   import or export operation works the way that you want it to.

If neither of those methods work for you and your '.asc' was generated by MATLAB then you may be able to use MATLAB to export directly to an Excel worksheet. MATLAB has a function [xlswrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) that you can use to write directly to a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet.

Another option, if you're comfortable writing some VBA code in Excel, is to [use the textscan function to parse your '.asc' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147913/i-am-trying-to-read-a-tab-delimited-text-file-and-store-certain-parts-of-the-dat?rq=1).